# Retrieve records from Rule Table

Tags: sql, oracle

Rule Table

[show rule table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCL5K.png)

Have created function which can evaluate different expressions in record depending on input

```
create or replace FUNCTION EVALUATERULE(colvalue varchar2 ,inputvalue varchar2)
return number
as
temp_result varchar2(1000);
result  number; 
begin
if colvalue = '*' or colvalue = 'NULL'
then
result := 1;
elsif regexp_instr(colvalue, '[>|<|!=|=|<>|<=|>=]',1,1,0,'i')=1 and regexp_like(inputvalue,'[^a-zA-Z]') then
    temp_result :='select decode(count(1),0,0,1)  from (select r1  from (select (r-1)/100 r1 from (select rownum r from all_objects where rownum  <100002)) where r1'|| colvalue ||') where r1 = '|| inputvalue;
  execute immediate temp_result into result;
elsif regexp_instr(colvalue, 'in',1,1,0,'i')=1 then  
  temp_result :='select decode(count(1),0,0,1)  from  dual where regexp_like('''||colvalue||''','''|| inputvalue||''')';
  execute immediate temp_result into result;
elsif regexp_instr(colvalue, 'not',1,1,0,'i')=1 then  
      temp_result :='select decode(count(1),0,1,0)  from  dual where regexp_like('''||colvalue||''','''|| inputvalue||''')';
   execute immediate temp_result into result;
elsif regexp_like(colvalue, '^\*[a-zA-Z]') or regexp_like(colvalue, '[a-zA-Z]\*$') then        
  temp_result :='select decode(count(1),0,0,1)  from  dual where  '''||inputvalue||'''  like regexp_replace('''||colvalue||''',''\*'',''%'',1,0,''i'')';
   execute immediate temp_result into result; 
else
   temp_result :='select decode(count(1),0,0,1)  from  dual where '''||colvalue||'''='''||inputvalue||'''';
  execute immediate temp_result into result; 
end if; 
return result;
END EVALUATERULE;
```

Created corresponding Stored Procedure to call this function for every column and retrieve matching rule

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_CUSTOMER_RULES(
    SCO_CUSTOMER_CD_I IN VARCHAR2,
    MAX_VOL_I IN VARCHAR2,
    MIN_VOL_I IN VARCHAR2,
    MIN_WT_I IN VARCHAR2,
    MAX_WT_I IN VARCHAR2,
    MIN_CARTONS_I IN VARCHAR2,
    MAX_CARTONS_I IN VARCHAR2,
    MIN_PALLETS_I IN VARCHAR2,
    MAX_PALLETS_I IN VARCHAR2,
    PRIORITY_I IN VARCHAR2,
    ORDER_TYPE_I IN VARCHAR2,
    ROUTE_I IN VARCHAR2,
    SHIPTO_COUNTRY_I IN VARCHAR2,
    RULE_SEQ_O OUT VARCHAR2,
    CARRIER_O OUT VARCHAR2,
    SHIP_VIA_O OUT VARCHAR2,
    LOGISTIC_UNIT_O OUT VARCHAR2,
    CARTON_LABEL_TYPE_O OUT VARCHAR2 
) AS 
BEGIN
select  RULE_SEQ,CARRIER,SHIP_VIA,LOGISTIC_UNIT,CARTON_LABEL_TYPE INTO RULE_SEQ_O,CARRIER_O,SHIP_VIA_O,LOGISTIC_UNIT_O,CARTON_LABEL_TYPE_O
        from (select  t.*,
        EVALUATERULE(SCO_CUSTOMER_CD, SCO_CUSTOMER_CD_I) cd,
        EVALUATERULE(MAX_VOL, MAX_VOL_I) maxVol,
        EVALUATERULE(MIN_VOL, MIN_VOL_I) minVol,
        EVALUATERULE(MIN_WT, MIN_WT_I) minWT,
        EVALUATERULE(MAX_WT, MAX_WT_I) maxWT,
        EVALUATERULE(MIN_CARTONS, MIN_CARTONS_I) minCARTONS,
        EVALUATERULE(MAX_CARTONS, MAX_CARTONS_I) maxCARTONS,
        EVALUATERULE(MIN_PALLETS, MIN_PALLETS_I) minPALLETS,
        EVALUATERULE(MAX_PALLETS, MAX_PALLETS_I) maxPALLETS,
        EVALUATERULE(PRIORITY, PRIORITY_I) prty,
        EVALUATERULE(ORDER_TYPE, ORDER_TYPE_I) ordTyp,
        EVALUATERULE(ROUTE, ROUTE_I) rte,  
        EVALUATERULE(SHIPTO_COUNTRY, SHIPTO_COUNTRY_I) shpToCty
        from SCO_CS_CUSTOM_CARRIER_RULESBKP t) where cd=1 and maxVol=1 and minVol=1 and minWT =1 and maxWT = 1 and minCARTONS = 1 and maxCARTONS = 1 and minPALLETS = 1 and maxPALLETS = 1 and prty=1 and ordTyp =1 
and rte = 1 and shpToCty=1 ORDER BY RULE_SEQ ASC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
END GET_CUSTOMER_RULES;
```

This is working as expected but the question is whether there is better way to do this then to evaluate through function for every column ?